# Possible to install packages to a separate Linux installation?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, live-usb, bios

So I was trying to get a CentOS designed application to work on Ubuntu, and played around with some graphics drivers. Well, in my spree of copy and pasting SE suggestions into my terminal, I broke something bad. I no longer have any GUI, and am stuck in tty. Trying to run `startx` tells me that `/usr/bin/X` doesn't exist. Awesome. I think I could fix it with

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

but I can't do this because I have no internet connection from tty, and cannot find any working solution to get wifi connected using `wpa_supplicant`, or anything else. As far as I understand, recovery mode will be useless too, without an internet connection.

So, instead I installed an Ubuntu 16.04 image onto a USB stick, and booted from there (which is what I'm typing this post from). Here, I have access to all my files, great, and have  GUI and internet connection working fine.

Now, is there a way for me to repair my original Ubuntu while having booted from the USB? I don't really know how `apt-get` works, but I would imagine there should be some way to download the `ubuntu-desktop` files while I have internet connection, and then reboot into my original Ubuntu's tty, and do the install. No? Suggestions?

Edit:

Okay, I can

`sudo apt-get install --download-only ubuntu-desktop --reinstall`

to get the `deb` package file onto the live-usb. Now figuring out how to move it to my machine/access it from my other installation...

Comment: In tty; were you in runlevel 1 (no networking, no gui) & didn't realize it?   *I realize from your description you believe you've destroyed gui, but I'm wondering if you bypassed issues by putting yourself in single-user mode which caused the no networking*

Comment: I believe you can mount your main hdd from live system, and put the file there.

Comment: @Emmet Hmm, one would think... I can't solve permissions issues

Comment: @guiverc sorry, I'm not sure what your comment means

Comment: In live system, you don't need password to invoke root access. Simply `sudo su` will grant you a root access

Comment: if you enter `runlevel` you'll be told what runlevel you are running (*actually previous & current*).  My comment was to ensure you hadn't changed your runlevel/init level down below where networking becomes enabled...  Graphics/gui should not impact networking, and so I wondered if you'd not considered the effects of your various pasted SE commands...